# Sherlock Action Bar not working below API level 11 devices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am now working with Action Bar Sherlock with Fragment Master Flow. Following [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/) tutorial & Now in the last phase.  After following all task I faced an error. I add a ABS jar file with my project which can be found after importing ABS Library Project in Eclipse --->> ABSLibProject > Libs > ABSJAR FILE.

I can't add  **android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"**  in manifest file. So, I can't run my project, below API 11 device. I runs my project on Samsung galaxy  4.1.2 , works fine on it.

When run this below API 11 lets say  2.3.3 emulator I got an error like,

`10-12 03:16:10.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 03:16:10.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.actionbarsherlock.R$styleable
10-12 03:16:10.540: E/AndroidRuntime(1483): at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.generateLayout(ActionBarSherlockCompat.java:973)`

Hope somebody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I add a ABS jar file with my project which can be found after importing ABS Library Project in Eclipse --->> ABSLibProject > Libs > ABSJAR FILE.

That is incorrect.

ActionBarSherlock is an Android library project, and you need to use it that way. This is covered in [the ActionBarSherlock documentation](http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html).

Comment: Wao..Murpy..I give you feed back soon.